# OpenVPN log file deleted, no more new logs

Tags: openvpn

Someone on my team deleted the openvpn.log files while the vpn server is still running.

Now for some reason no new log file is being created by openvpn and therefor, we have no more logs.

Is there anyway to force openvpn to resume logging to the file without needing to restart it?

Comment: What happens if you ceate a new file (`touch openvpn.log`)?

Comment: Nothing, File stays empty (It has write permissions for everyone)

Comment: Try to send it a SIGHUP, it should reread config, and reopen log files.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `openvpn` (2.5.1 at least) will not reopen the logfile on `SIGHUP` or any other event short of restarting. If you don't want to restart but want to read the deleted (but still growing) logfile, you can

```
# tail /proc/`pidof openvpn`/fd/2
```

You can also rotate the logfile without deleting it using `copytruncate` option of `logrotate` as suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74602/openvpn-logrotate).